# How to make disable to show zoom pane in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

Can anyone help me about AChartEngine. Here the first thing I need is not to show zoom icon with the chart and also not to show x,y labels. But I could not find any solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` methods
to enable or disable zooming and pan like this.

```
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
renderer.setZoomRate(0.2f);
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

and regarding removing the X, Y labels, I think you cannot remove labels. Workaround is to pass an empty `String` (i.e `""`).
For further reference you can download their [Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list), under `achartengine-0.6.0-javadocs.zip`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I am able to removing labels also using the following code:renderer.setShowLabels(false);But I face some other problem. Actually I do not want to show anything in title. I can do this setting String title = "" but in the chart it since title field is empty it do not show text but it show a line. the second problem is that I need the last point(x,y value) of the carve which is drawn. Is it possible?

Comment: can u help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159890/how-to-remove-extra-spacing-from-piechart