# achartengine - Android

Tags: android, achartengine

Ok, so I'm trying to render a TimeChart in achartengine on an android machine. Everything is working as intended except I cannot disable panning and zooming. The code is as follows:

```
dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(sRenderer);
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
Intent i = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

So it behaves as expected except for the panning and zooming functionality.
Any ideas?

I am running achartengine version 0.7.0

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503563/how-to-make-disable-to-show-zoom-pane-in-achartengine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the methods in the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer:

```
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```