# How to draw a pie chart in android

Tags: android, graph

I'd like to draw a pie chart in my android application.
Would you please suggest me a way to do that in a simple way ?
I have written a view class for that purpose but it's not satisfying. So I would appreciate if you tell me a good and high performance chart library.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731261/android-draw-circle-with-2-colors-pie-chart

Comment: This tutorial should help some one.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWJB1NLFJGg

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Download the jar from

http://www.achartengine.org/content/download.html

Add the jar to the projects lib folder. There is a sample also provided by the developers. You can check that and modify the same as you wish.

There is also a demo @

http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html

The docs

http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/chart/PieChart.html

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity class

```
public class AChartEnginePieChartActivity extends Activity { 

    private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE,Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };

    private static double[] VALUES = new double[] { 10, 11, 12, 13 };

    private static String[] NAME_LIST = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

    private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");

    private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();

    private GraphicalView mChartView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);

        for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.length; i++) {
            mSeries.add(NAME_LIST[i] + " " + VALUES[i], VALUES[i]);
            SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1) % COLORS.length]);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        }

        if (mChartView != null) {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
            mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
            mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

            mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

                    if (seriesSelection == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"No chart element was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"Chart element data point index "+ (seriesSelection.getPointIndex()+1) + " was clicked" + " point value="+ seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                    if (seriesSelection == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"No chart element was long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        return false; 
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(AChartEnginePieChartActivity.this,"Chart element data point index "+ seriesSelection.getPointIndex()+ " was long pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        return true;       
                    }
                }
            });
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
        else {
        mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Raghunandan : how to invisible `label text`  and `legend text` vertically align

Comment: For anyone wondering how to include the achartengine lib as a managed dependency to Gradle: add `repositories { maven { url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/" } }` in your global `build.gradle`(to `buildscript` and `allprojects`), then add `compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'` to your dependencies in the `build.gradle` of your module.

Comment: how can i make disable to moveing pie chart?

Comment: I am working as per above pie-chart approach.my problem is it keep spacing around piechar.can u help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159890/how-to-remove-extra-spacing-from-piechart

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use thrid-party libraries, you can use this formula to get points on the circle, given radius `r`:

```
x = r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI) //This will give you r
y = r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI) //This will give you 0
```

For other points of the circle you need to modify your cosine argument, for example:

```
x = r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI / 6) //This will give you r/2
y = r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / 6) //This will give you r*sqrt(3/2)
```

If you want to fill out the entire circle with a fixed step n:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    x = r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n)
    y = r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n)
    //Draw PointF(x,y)
}
```

Comment: nice idea. but with this you will need a custom view an draw circle and use paint object to color parts of the circle.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. AChartEngine is great library for displaying fixed values as a chart, I posted an answer only to illustrate mathematical approach with native SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Another library is PAcPie Char, you can take a look :

https://github.com/marshallino16/PacPieChart-Android

I'm still writing it but at least, it's a beginning

Comment: It's at the moment a simple POC but do not hesitate to fork and pull request :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have best Pie Chart do as follows:
1. Open build.gradle(Modul: app) add dependence `implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'`

2.Create Your_Layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/piechart_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300sp">
        </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
    </LinearLayout>
```

3. Open Your activity file and paste the following codes:

   ```
   public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

           protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
   {
             super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
             setPieChart(); }

            public void setPieChart() {
                       this.pieChart = pieChart;
                       pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
                       pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(true);
                       pieChart.setExtraOffsets(5,10,5,5);
                       pieChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
                       pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);
                       pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
                       pieChart.animateY(1000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutCubic);
                       ArrayList<PieEntry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();
                       yValues.add(new PieEntry(34f,"Ilala"));
                       yValues.add(new PieEntry(56f,"Temeke"));
                       yValues.add(new PieEntry(66f,"Kinondoni"));
                       yValues.add(new PieEntry(45f,"Kigamboni"));

                       PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yValues, "Desease Per 
                        Regions");
                       dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
                       dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);
                       dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                       PieData pieData = new PieData((dataSet));
                       pieData.setValueTextSize(10f);
                       pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                       pieChart.setData(pieData);
                       //PieChart Ends Here
                   }
   }
   ```

It Will Give you Pie Chart shown Below;
[image]

The Library can also be used for Drawing Bar Graphs, LineGraphs,Horizontal Bar Graphs Etc

Comment: @BjörnHallström using same library but its not showing all lables if legend is vertically shown right to pieChart

Comment: @Erum you can change the legend position

Comment: @eli How is it the "best Pie Chart"?

Answer (score 2):

I think your best friend is [aChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/).
It's easy to use and provides a wide range of charts to display.

Example of a pie chart:

[image]

Comment: how can i disable movingand zooming.

Comment: @Vasant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503563/how-to-make-disable-to-show-zoom-pane-in-achartengine

Comment: how can in increase radius of pie?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any third party library,try sample form google.
They provide a sample to draw pie chart in their Custom Drawing documentation.

[Documentation and sample code can be found here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Open up build.gradle (module:app) and add the library in the dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
```

Next you need to open up build.gradle (Project) and add Jcenter because this library is available through it.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

Now sync your project by clicking on Sync Now.

Open up activity_main.xml and add the following code for Android pie chart view.

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context="com.codingdemos.codingdemos.MainActivity">
<lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.PieChartView
android:id="@+id/chart"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
< /LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for MainActivity.java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    PieChartView pieChartView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pieChartView = findViewById(R.id.chart);

    List pieData = new ArrayList<>();
    pieData.add(new SliceValue(15, Color.BLUE).setLabel("Q1: $10"));
    pieData.add(new SliceValue(25, Color.GRAY).setLabel("Q2: $4"));
    pieData.add(new SliceValue(10, Color.RED).setLabel("Q3: $18"));
    pieData.add(new SliceValue(60, Color.MAGENTA).setLabel("Q4: $28"));

    PieChartData pieChartData = new PieChartData(pieData);
    pieChartData.setHasLabels(true).setValueLabelTextSize(14);
    pieChartData.setHasCenterCircle(true).setCenterText1("Sales in million").setCenterText1FontSize(20).setCenterText1Color(Color.parseColor("#0097A7"));
    pieChartView.setPieChartData(pieChartData);
}
}
```

you can see https://www.codingdemos.com/android-pie-chart-tutorial/ for more description.