# Android - PieChart from text file

Tags: android, pie-chart, file-read

I am trying to create a pie chart in android whose input values are read from a text file. I have a problem in parsing the data and assigning it to the distribution series and setting the color for the pie chart. Any sample code for this would be of great help.

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835628/how-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-android

Comment: In this link all the values are given in array in the program itself. i.e, colors, values and name_list which is kinda hard coded. I want to read those values from the text file..

Answer (score 0):

Please check code for achartEngine. i think your problem resolved using achartEngine. See the below link.

https://github.com/jondwillis/AChartEngine/tree/master/achartengine

Answer (score 0):

You just check out how to use google chart from this below link
http://psychopyko.com/tutorial/how-to-use-google-charts/ and let me know whether it is useful or not.