# Draw circle which is filled horizontally in Android

Tags: android, canvas, draw, achartengine, pie-chart

To draw circles and pie charts in Android, we can use the [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/download.html) Android framework as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20835670/2459449).

However, how can we draw circles that is partly filled horizontally (or vertically) in Android? I mean circles which are filled, for example, from the bottom to the top according to the percentage specified in Java code.

Here is a preview of what we need:

[image: Preview]

Comment: I've an example of one way to do that in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858531/filling-a-circle-gradually-from-bottom-to-top-android). Actually, two ways, if you check the revision history for the initial post. My initial answer, however, only works in API 19 and above.

Comment: Your answer is better and so simple (one utility class). Thank you @MikeM.

Answer (score 7):

Try this lib [Circle Progress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress).
Here is a sample from lib's author:

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

[image: circle]

Comment: I find some difficulty to implement and run successfully this lib/code. This lib is though detailed and provides many ways of progress forms in Android. Thank you @Minhtdh.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `Drawable` and let your `draw` method look like this:

```
public void draw(Canvas c) {
    float size = ...; // The size of your circle
    Paint color = new Paint();
    color.setColor(...); // Color of your circle
    c.drawCircle(size / 2, size / 2, size / 2, color);
    Path p = new Path();
    float ratio = ...; // How many of the circle you want to have filled
    float offset = size * (float) Math.sqrt(1-((double) (0.5-ratio) * 2)*((double) (0.5-ratio) * 2)) / 2;
    float angle = (float) Math.asin((double) (0.5-ratio) * 2);
    p.addArc(offset, size * (1-percent), size - offset, size, angle, Math.PI - angle);
    p.close();
    c.drawPath(p, color);
}
```