# Pie chart is not displayed

Tags: java, android, charts

I am trying to create an android app using DecoView lib for displaying a Pie chart, but I can't get it to display the pie chart.

**a.xml**

```xml
<com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/dynamicArcView"
  android:layout_margin="8dp">
</com.hookedonplay.decoviewlib.DecoView>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

This is the Activity where I am going to call chart class.

**a.java**

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a);
    listViewRoom = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.listView2);
    getVal();
}

public void getVal(){
    //get value from json
    new SamplePeopleFragment();//in these function it is not going 
}
```

I used the SamplePeopleFragment.java object which is found in in the DecoView project, but it is not working.

[Pie Chart](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2329)

I created my application based on the example found at the link above.

Comment: Here you can find good example of  [Pie Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835628/how-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-android)

Comment: Your `DecoView` is in activity xml file `a.xml` so i think you need to configure it in your activity `a.java`.