# How to remove extra spacing from piechart?

Tags: android, android-studio, charts, pie-chart, space

I am working on pie-chart. **problem is it keep spacing around piechart**.
how can i remove extra spacing from piechart.

[image]

***Your answer would be appreciated***

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try calling `setOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)` on the Chart

**EX**

```
chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
```

check [Modifying the Viewport](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding below line to dataset:

```
dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);
```